# QTableView и QMouseEvent

Tags: qt, qt4, mouse-event

Имеется ли возможность отлавливать `mouseReleaseEvent` на `QTableView`?

Порывшись в исходниках Qt 4.8, понял, что для `QTableView` нет метода `mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)`. Создал свой класс, наследующийся от `QTableView`, и в нем переопределил `mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*)`. В дизайнере преобразовал стандартный `QTableView` в свой класс-наследник.

Но в итоге все равно события нажатия правой/левой кнопки мыши на `QTableView` не отлавливаются.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решился установкой `eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)` на `QTableView` таким образом: `tableView->viewport()->installEventFilter(this);` и в самом классе соответственно переопределил `bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event);` и повесил нужные действия на соответствующие event'ы.